# Remoteexception error on EC2 in parallel julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to run some parallel code in Julia on an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 server and when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: `+` has no method matching +(::RemoteException, ::RemoteException)
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...)
 in mapreduce_seq_impl at ./reduce.jl:228
while loading /home/ubuntu/GameenderProd.jl, in expression starting on line 8
```

This is the code that generates the error:

```
using DecisionTree
@everywhere include("GameenderDrone.jl")
for i=0:4:8
 for j=0:4:60
    for k=0:4:8
    for l=0:4:60
        if i + j < 61 && k + l < 61 && (i<k || (i==k && j<=l))
rt=Matrix(0,1)          
for q=1:100
        library1=creatlib(j,i)
        library2=creatlib(l,k)
    player1=Player(Int8(1),Int8(20),[],[],[],[],[],Int8(0),Int8(8),Int8(size(library1)[1]))
    player2=Player(Int8(2),Int8(20),[],[],[],[],[],Int8(0),Int8(8),Int8(size(library2)[1]))
    player1.hand=library1[1:7]
player2.hand=library2[1:7]

    rt=[rt; StartTable(library1,library2,player1,player2)]
end

result=pmap(gamerunner,rt)
total=sum(result)-100
rt=Matrix(0,1)
for q=1:100

        library1=creatlib(l,k)
        library2=creatlib(j,i)
    player1=Player(Int8(1),Int8(20),[],[],[],[],[],Int8(0),Int8(8),Int8(size(library1)[1]))
    player2=Player(Int8(2),Int8(20),[],[],[],[],[],Int8(0),Int8(8),Int8(size(library2)[1]))
    player1.hand=library1[1:7]
player2.hand=library2[1:7]

    rt=[rt; StartTable(library1,library2,player1,player2)]
end
negresult=pmap(gamerunner,rt)
total2=200-sum(negresult)
sumtotal=total + total2
output=[total total2 sumtotal] 
cd("//home/ubuntu/result")
test=string(i,"C",j,"Lv",k,"C",l,"L.csv")
writedlm(test,output,",")
cd("//home/ubuntu")
end
end
end
end
end
```

When I test it with one worker on Juliabox (after changing the cd commands) it seems to work.  Can anyone explain this error to me?

EDIT: Testing it on Juliabox with 12 workers generates the following error, and it appears the first file finished

```
juser@juliabox:~$ julia -p 12                                                                                                                                        
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                                                                                                                        

julia> include("GameenderProd.jl")
Worker 6 terminated.                                                                                                                                                 
ERROR (unhandled task failure): EOFError: read end of file                                                                                                           
ERROR: LoadError: ProcessExitedException()
Stacktrace:                                                                                                                                                          
 [1] #568 at ./asyncmap.jl:178 [inlined]
 [2] foreach(::Base.##568#570, ::Array{Any,1}) at ./abstractarray.jl:1731
 [3] maptwice(::Function, ::Channel{Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,2}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,2},N} where N) at ./asyncmap.jl:178
 [4] wrap_n_exec_twice(::Channel{Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.Distributed.##204#207{WorkerPool}, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,2},N} where N) at ./a
syncmap.jl:154                                                                                                                                                       
 [5] #async_usemap#553(::Function, ::Void, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.##188#190, ::Array{Any,2}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,2},N} where N) at ./asyncmap.jl:103
 [6] (::Base.#kw##async_usemap)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#async_usemap, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}, ::Vararg{Array{Any,2},N} where N) at ./<missing>:0
 [7] (::Base.#kw##asyncmap)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#asyncmap, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}) at ./<missing>:0
 [8] #pmap#203(::Bool, ::Int64, ::Void, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Void, ::Function, ::WorkerPool, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:126
 [9] pmap(::WorkerPool, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:101
 [10] #pmap#213(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{Any,2}) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:156
 [11] macro expansion at /home/juser/GameenderProd.jl:40 [inlined]
 [12] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
 [13] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:569
 [14] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
while loading /home/juser/GameenderProd.jl, in expression starting on line 9
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us where you put the parallel for loops in the code?  By your description, the code you posted works.  Can you post the code that generates the error?

Comment: The above code does not work.  I am trying to run the above code on Amazon EC2.  On my computer, just using Julia, not with any workers, I can run

`for i=0:4:8
 for j=0:4:60
    for k=0:4:8
    for l=0:4:60
        if i + j < 61 && k + l < 61 && (i<k || (i==k && j<=l))
println("A")
end
end
end
end
end`
and it works

Comment: Can you edit this to a minimally runnable piece of code which generates the error? Your example won't run because it's missing the definition of the function `gamerunner`, and it's missing the `.csv` files, so I have no idea where to begin debugging your code because I cannot run it myself. Instead, you should share an example which recreates the problem without extra details. Maybe you'll find out what's wrong in the process, or if not, edit the question and we can help you from there. As it stands, the description of the problem is too vague to offer any real help.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I started looking at what was causing the RemoteExceptions.  I found ""cannot resize array with shared data".  I am not sure how to address this.  I found a simple way to recreate this error was:

Comment: `@everywhere type Player
    num::Int8
life::Int8
hand::Array{Char,1}
untmt::Array{Char,1}
tpmt::Array{Char,1} 
untc::Array{Char,1} 
    tpc::Array{Char,1}
nm::Bool 
    tc::Int8    
    sl::Int8 
end
@everywhere function test(player)
              for i=1:100
              push!(player.hand,'M')
              end
              end
 rt=Matrix(5,1)
for q=1:5
       rt[q]=Player(Int8(1),Int8(20),[],[],[],[],[],Int8(0),Int8(8),Int8(60))
       end
 pmap(test,rt)`

Comment: I seemed to find a solution to this - simply make a deepcopy of the input variables so that they don't change.